# Drop down leaves gap in navigation when hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my current CSS navigation responsive for mobile devices.

I currently have it set up with a media query so that when the screen width falls below the specified size it changes to block form (stacked) and a menu icon appears on the right hand side of the logo (to later be made into a button).

The problem I'm currently having is that the drop down menu which is used for my second link in the navigation, is causing a gap to appear between the second and third link (as if the drop down content is taking up the space whilst hidden).

I've tried looking for solutions but can't seem to find the right answer for my particular setup. Basically, the link "How It Works" should sit right beneath "Sections" when on mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/fc45c7p5/

> 

```
        <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:330px;height:100px"/>
        </a>

        <div id="menu-icon">&#57349;</div>
        <br></br>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar cf">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">SECTIONS</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="retail.html">RETAIL</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">RESTAURANT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">SHOPPING</a></li>
                                </ul>
                <li><a href="how.html">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>                
                <li><a href="#">OUR EXPERIENCE</a></li>                 
                <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>

            </ul>
    </div>
```

Don't take too much note of the media query max-width of 1008px, I'm aware this isn't standard mobile size, it's just temporary whilst I get it working first.

Any help regarding this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visibility` keeps your elements there without displaying them. You should use `display:none` when you do not want show the space the hidden element takes. Use `display:block` to show them again. Add some CSS transitions to the height of the `a` elements to make the reveal somewhat smoother.

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/6eshy7n2/

Comment: Thanks alot. That worked. I was sure it was display:none but I forgot about display:block to reveal it again.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following.

```
ul.navbar ul li { float: none; width: 100%; display:none;}
ul.navbar li:hover > ul li{display: block;}
```

You have to make the `li`s inside the `ul`s actually not display when the parent `li` is not being hovered. When it is hovered you then change the `display` value to `block` to make it visible.